# How to convert a docker-compose file to Kubernetes YAML file?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, kubernetes-pod

How to convert the following code for docker-compose to Kubernetes YAML file.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./init-mongo.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-mongo.js:ro
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need several components, firstly, a service, that will get the http request. Then a Deployment to create the actual pod, if you need volume so also a Persistent Volume.  In my [repository](https://github.com/Shachar297/Nexus-Registry) you can find docker compose yaml converted to k8s. Of course, you will probably need to change some data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to import the init-mongo.js file, which contains the DB info without using the Persistent Volume? Is it possible through the YAML code with configmap type?

Comment: Of course, what you need to do is to write you own dockerfile, based on the original mongo image, and copy your code into the container. Then instead of using the image from docker hub, use you own image.

Answer (score 0):

The [kompose project](https://kompose.io/) is a project that provides a tool that does specifically this -- converts a docker-compose file into a set of Kubernetes yaml files. It might be worth a look for you.

For simple docker-compose files like this it would work fine. But for more complicated ones, it might over-complicate things, so YMMV and all.

Comment: From what I've seen in other SO questions, Kompose needs manual help even in very simple setups.  For example, in this question, it will need help creating a ConfigMap for the initialization script.  It's useful as a starting point or inspiration but not a complete solution.

Comment: Agreed. I tried using it for one of my projects, and it made a complete unintelligible mess so much so I just build my own yamls from scratch, but I did use the kompose yamls as a starting point.